# Excel - trying to identify top 3 sales numbers in column d, and return information from corresponding column a

Tags: excel-formula

Excel - trying to identify top 3 sales numbers in column D (D5:D:41), and return information from corresponding column A (A5:A41)

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? Perhaps sample data, and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the top 3 with

```
=INDEX($A$5:$A$41,MATCH(LARGE($D$5:$D$41,ROW(A1)),$D$5:$D$41,0))
```

Copy down two rows.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pivot table to very easily get his information.

- Select insert a pivot table
- Select your data
- In the pivot table window place the 'Name' field into the 'Row Labels' box and the 'Sales' field into the 'Values' box.

This should give you a pivot table with a list of people and the sum of their sales, making it very easy to see who comes out top.